# android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8 is not recognised

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm trying to build [MVICore sample project from badoo.](https://github.com/badoo/MVICore)

But having an error as;

```
Unresolved reference: LifecycleOwner
Unresolved reference: arch
Unresolved reference: AndroidLifecycle
```

Basically the all `android.arch` is not recognised.
There is no androidx in the project so it's using
`"android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8"`  version **1.1.1**

For `LifeCycleObserver` Android Studio recommends me to import `androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver`

Developers of the project said it works on their pc, I tried with different pc and it worked.

When I do those changes (using androidx libraries) https://github.com/badoo/MVICore/pull/131/files, it works but developers of the project said it doesn't work for them with my changes.

I use

```
Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
```

And

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'` solves the issue.